# Send selector to another class

Tags: iphone, selector

How do I send a selector to another class? I want to send a selector from a subview to the main view to push the next view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SEL selectorToSend = @selector(mySuperDuperMessage:);
[otherClass iWantASelector:selectorToSend];
```

otherClass:

```
@interface{
SEL aSelector;
}

@implementation{
-(void) iWantASelector:(SEL) newSelector
{
    aSelector = newSelector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this construction:

```
[self.superView performSelector:@selector(Test:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

[James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330727/send-selector-to-another-class/7330799#7330799) is about right, but I'd ask yourself why you need to do this rather than passing a block, which will give you much more flexibility, especially with it's ability to transfer state.